# Skobbler for Bus/truck routing

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

Can we use skobbler navigation feature for Bus or Truck type, as of now i am using eficient route mode which takes  car fastest route. is there any option for taking bus route? 
I am using SDK 2.5

Answer (score 0):

**Truck:** there is no support for truck routing (no truck specific attributes like road weight/height limit, or truck specific restrictions)

**Bus:** there is no support for bus routing (no bus specific attributes like bus only lanes).

This being said, for buses, there are a number of flags that you can take advantage of like: a car-bus routing profile that creates a route disregarding car restrictions (giving you the possibility of navigating car one way streets) and offering ETAs more intune with a bus' movement speed and a flag forcing that all via points be approached on the right (corresponding to a bus' doors)